# Pass variable to helper.php

Tags: php, variables, joomla

Having a bit of a mind blank at the moment.
I have an input field and trying to pass the value of the input when the form is submitted, to a function in the helper.php

**default.php**

```
<input name="value" type="text" />
<input name="delete" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

**mod_xxxxxx.php**

```
if(isset($post['delete'])) {
    $delete = $post['value'];
    modXxxxxxxHelper::delete($delete);
}
```

**helper.php**

```
function delete($delete) {
    $value = //get the variable 
}
```

How can I can the value of the input field which will then define `$value`?

**Please note that I am using Joomla 2.5 coding standards and therefore `$post` has already been defined and works correctly**

Comment: So the form in default.php has a post action because that is the first place I would look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're passing `$post['value']` to the method then you can just access that variable using `$delete`

```
function delete($delete) {
    // $delete would have the value of $post['value']
}
```

Comment: thanks you. been trying to figure this out for quite a while. much appreciated ;)